# Por que não consigo exibir o MessageBoxButtons se não for uma string?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sintaxe

Por que não estou a conseguir exibir o `MessageBoxButtons` caso não seja uma string?

```
static void Main()
{
    string texto = "Minha primeira MessageBox";
    MessageBoxButtons botao = MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel;
    DialogResult result;
    result = MessageBox.Show(texto, botao);
    if(result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Isso ai");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Porque esta sintaxe não existe. Só existe um método que aceita o `MessageBoxButtons` se houver 2 parâmetros `string` antes (o segundo é o *caption*):

```
result = MessageBox.Show(texto, "Proceder", botao);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/MessageBox.cs).

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_Windows_Forms_MessageBox_Show_System_String_System_String_System_Windows_Forms_MessageBoxButtons_).

[Lista de sobrecargas existentes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#overloads).

Comment: A sim agora compreendi.
Quando ia conferir na documentação, não via nada especificando que precisava de dois parâmetros strings antes de um MessageBoxButtons. Mas também devia ter ficado mas atento aos exemplos.
Muito obrigado mesmo

Comment: Se resolveu seu problema você pode aceitar a resposta, aí do lado.